# dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: __kminitAdmob

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, firebase, admob

I have got a runtime error while trying to run on ios simulator (XCODE 8 , MACOS Sierra), my app built on Unity, build succeed but runtime error occured.

Error: **dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: __kminitAdmob**

Is there anybody has any idea ?

Comment: sounds like a plugin isn't installed correctly. What plugins are you using?

Comment: AdmobPlugin.a + GoogleMobileAds.framework installed, when build for android, it is running succesfuly but for ios not !

Comment: Make sure you're using the [official unity plugin](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-unity). Also make sure that in xcode you have both C and Objective-C Modules enabled.

Comment: I prefer Firebase-Admob-Unity plugin, https://github.com/unity-plugins/Firebase-Admob-Unity

Comment: That should work as well, I always use the other one though, so that might be the reason why it's not working for you. Maybe try reinstalling the plugin?

Comment: Thank you Jesper !  re-installed plugin (latest version) and also I set both C and Objective-C Modules enabled in xcode build settings, it works !